# bootstrap modal pops up and stick there

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a table with two rows and each one has button . I want the second button pops up a modal but when I run my code the window modal that is supposed to pop up by me clicking on the "View Cart" button doesn't pop up . instead it's already there when I change my page to the page where i have the "View Cart" button. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <div class="btn_form" style="length :150px;">
     <form method="post"  action="single.php">
 <input type="image" name="cart" value=<?php echo $array[0]['ProductID']?>image src="img/cart.png height="100px" width="100px" onClick="document.submitForm.hidbrand.value=this.value; document.submitForm.submit();" />
   </form>
   </div>
       </tr>
           <tr>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View Cart</button>
             <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your modal outside the table, and you forgot to include the first two DIVs that define the modal scaffolding.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <div class="btn_form" style="length :150px;">
      <form method="post" action="single.php">
        <input type="image" name="cart" value="<?php echo $array[0]['ProductID']; ?>" src="img/cart.png" height="100px" width="100px" onClick="document.submitForm.hidbrand.value=this.value; document.submitForm.submit();" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View Cart</button>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

References:

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp